# Full Calendar not work or nothing show?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, fullcalendar

This my code.

```
    @{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link href="~/Style/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"  ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Custom/fullcalendar.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Custom/moment.min.js"></script>   
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        })
    });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Doing with asp.net MVC project.It nothing show.What happen and what need more in my code?I just follow do with [FullCalendar Basic Usage](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/) .Thanks.

Comment: from the documentation page of fullcalendar - *jQuery and **Moment** must be loaded **before** FullCalendar's JavaScript* - so, that's one fail, as you have moment **after** fullcalendar - perhaps you can look at your browsers developer tools console for any other errors you may be getting

Comment: @Jaromanda , When i changed moment.js to before fullcalendar,really work!.This little trick take my 3 hour. Ohh! Very very big thanks,

Comment: sorry i cant up vote your comment because my reputation is low :(.

Comment: I'm not here for stack overflow points :p otherwise I'd have posted it as an answer :p

Comment: Ok, God bless you.